# Why do questions posted on Chemistry.SE get automatically transferred to a different site?

Tags: discussion

When I was looking for an answer for my question [Why does 1,4-diiodobenzene have a non-zero dipole moment?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/135413/81509) asked on the main site (a few days ago), I came across 'exactly' the same question posted on a [different forum](https://solveforum.com/threads/why-does-1-4-diiodobenzene-have-a-non-zero-dipole-moment.521503/#post-521532) on the same day. To double check this observation, I looked for the question [What single, pure compound would best replace petrol?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/67322/81509) asked on the main site (in the year 2017) to be also copied [there](https://solveforum.com/threads/what-single-pure-compound-would-best-replace-petrol.448079/). But it is dated to be April 30, 2020. I guess this process started only this year. More examples can be found by simply putting the title from this site to the tiny search box there.

I don't know whether this has been discussed earlier. Why does this happen and what should we do? It seems like an attempt to drive some traffic towards their site. But is this activity allowed?

Comment: Is it just me, or have they copied all the LaTeX formatting too, and there's no hope of it rendering there?

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer: You're right. That site doesn't render $\LaTeX$ at all. If it becomes  necessary for you to view them properly then you can run the ChatJax script. Then, it shows the math expressions properly. Anyways, when we know where the original is why do we need to refer the duplicate? :)

Comment: Yes, I know, but that's not what I meant ;). I was highlighting their blatantly obvious plagiarism. Didn't even convert the $\LaTeX$ to readable plaintext or some image format.

Comment: It's not just for chem se, but for all of SE. My Math-SE was copied there as well. Probably they're data scraping, so post on meta.se.com if required

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Other sites have recognized the quality of Stack Exchange question and answers, and [started to copy them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/295232). If they abide by the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing), this is even allowed. It doens't look like the site you mentioned abides by that rule, so you're welcome to report this via the [Contact Us](/contact) form; there's a special option "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution" for this.